# Error No. 1045 : While trying to connect to MySql

Tags: mysql, windows, sqlyog

I installed *[SQLYog Community edition for windows](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list)*, a GUI tool for *MySql*. I had earlier installed MySql with XAMPP. Now when I am trying to connect , I see an error *(as pointed)*:

[image]

What could be the reason, I am getting this ? How do I connect to MySql and start using this GUI tool ?

Comment: "Access denied" seems pretty clear, doesn't it? Do you have a user account "suhail" set up?

Comment: @Pekka How do I connect to MySql. No

Comment: You need to connect with an existing account and set up users first. XAMPP creates a default mySQL user account, IIRC it's "root" with no password.

Comment: you can usually manage the users and connection with phpmyadmin: http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin - you have to start xampp-apache and xampp-mysql first unless it is installed as an active service

Comment: @Adder I even edited the root password with phpmyadmin:http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin but the same result

Comment: you need to reread the authentication data after editing it. Easiset way to do that is stopping the mysql service and restarting it. Or check the mysql manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html Be careful not to lock ypurself out ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says `access denied for suhail @localhost` . These could be the issues :

- The user `suhail` does not exist at locahost.
- The password specified is wrong.
- MySql Server is not started. If it is started the port number is not `3306`.

These are some of the troubleshoot techniques.

Also follow the comments on your question.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same error message, however, it is resolved by means of using admin password on my machine.  The message I get is as follows:

Connection info

> Connection successful!
>    MySQL version: 5.1.54-community

Then I clicked ok to continue.  See if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

error 1045 is a common authentication error

The user should be allowed to connect from remote hosts.
It should be defined as 'suhail'@'%' and not 'suhail'@'localhost')

http://webyog.com/faq/content/23/18/en/error-no-1045-connection-denied.html

```
* User is not allowed to connect from the actual host. Note that MySQL by default only allows connection from 'localhost'. To specify from where a user may connect SQL wildcards (% and _) can be used. Simply 'someuser@%' means that user 'someuser' may connect from everywhere.
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was having the same problem, but it was solved by giving.. username as- root.
So. try by giving
username: root.

Answer (score 0):

Go to mysql Workbench >> Users and privileges >>

Select user in user accounts tab, then on right side open schema privileges tab >> there you have to give required permissions.

If not work,

open a 3306 port in windows firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the port is already in use or not. 3306 port is for Mysql server. So check whether it is being used or not. if it is used then we can kill that process and can try again to connect to the same port.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to put the 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in mysqlhost address

mine is working